# MQTT on_message timeout in Python

Tags: python, mqtt

So I am trying to listen to periodic messages that are sent to a topic. The thing is, I would like to break if there is no new messages written to that topic after a period of time (say 2 seconds in the code below). Is there a way to do this, maybe is there built-in MQTT function that returns a periodically updated properties of a certain topic? I am attaching an imagination of what I would like to have (in Python)

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

def on_message(self, mqttc, obj, msg):
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.qos)+" "+str(msg.payload))


def listen_to_heartbeat(self):
    global status_heartbeat
    global terminate_heartbeat_listener
    status_heartbeat = 1
    terminate_heartbeat_listener = 0

    client = mqtt.Client()
    client.connect(broker, port, 3)
    client.on_message = on_message
    topic = "machine/gui/0/heartbeat"
    client.subscribe(topic, 0)

    no_message = 0
    while True:
        client.loop()
        if there is no new message on topic:
           no_message = no_message + 1
        if no_message == 5:
           print("no new message after 10s, exiting ...)
           break
        time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include on_connect and on_disconnect functions in your code. on_connect function is called after connecting to the client to ensure that connection is established.
So you can write on_connect function as

```
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    logging.info("Connected flags"+str(flags)+"result code " + str(rc)+ "client1_id")
    client.connected_flag=True
```

After that you need to define on_disconnect function to break the connection between client and broker if no message is received.

```
def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
    if rc != 0:
        print("Unexpected MQTT disconnection.")
```

rc (return code) is used for checking that the connection was established.
If rc!=0, it means connection is not successful and you can then stop the loop by writing

```
client.loop_stop()
```

But if you want to wait till the client reconnects to the broker write

```
client.loop_forever()
```

The sequence of calling these functions will be like

```
client.connect(broker, port, 3)
topic = "machine/gui/0/heartbeat"
client.subscribe(topic, 0)
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message=on_message 
client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect
client.loop_stop()
```

I think there is no need to write the while loop then. Try it.